# How to refresh dropdown list after setting index to 0?

Tags: c#, .net

I already have an event handler for a button that generates an excel report. (`ExportExcel(filename);` is the method that generates the excel report FYI) So that's fine and dandy.  What I'm trying to do now is refresh the dropdown list so it reflects what the correct Dropdown selection is.

I got it to set the dropdown list to the 0th index but the dropdown list doesn't change for some reason.  So I think I need to somehow individually reset the dropdown list.
Here's some code below. (I left in some comments and Debug.WriteLine()'s to show my thought process)

```
protected void GenerateButton1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // CustomerDropdown.ClearSelection();
            // CustomerDropdown.Items.Clear();
            // Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
            //////////
            // Below is resetting the CustomerDropdown list.
            ViewState["DropDownIndexSelection"] = CustomerDropdown.SelectedItem.Value.Trim();
            DataSet dataSet = (DataSet)ViewState["DropDownListDs"];
            var filename = "Customer ID - " + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
            ExportExcel(filename);
            // DataSet DropDownIndexSelection = (DataSet)ViewState["DropDownIndexSelection"];
            CustomerDropdown.Items.Clear();
            // CustomerDropdown.ClearSelection();
            CustomerDropdown.DataTextField = dataSet.Tables[0].Columns["cust_id"].ToString();
            CustomerDropdown.DataValueField = dataSet.Tables[0].Columns["cust_id"].ToString();
            CustomerDropdown.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];  //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist  
                                                              // CustomerDropdown.Items[0].Selected = true;
            CustomerDropdown.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist 
            CustomerDropdown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
            CustomerDropdown.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("All"));

            CustomerDropdown.Items.FindByValue("Please select").Selected = true;
            Debug.WriteLine(CustomerDropdown.Items.FindByValue("Please select").Selected == false);
            Debug.WriteLine(CustomerDropdown.Items.FindByValue("Please select").Selected == true);
return;
}
```

**How can I set the Dropdown back to "Please select" after running the `ExportExcel(filename)` method? I think basically what I'm asking is how do I refresh the `CustomerDropdown` after setting the selection to "Please select"**

Answer (score 0):

CustomerDropdown.SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: This selects the right index but the dropdown list doesn't refresh so it doesn't matter.  I edited my original question to ask essentially how to refresh the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

> after that it will select the 0th index selection, which is "Please select."

Have you tried adding to your code:

```
        ExportExcel(filename);
        // DataSet DropDownIndexSelection = (DataSet)ViewState["DropDownIndexSelection"];
        CustomerDropdown.Items.Clear();
        // CustomerDropdown.ClearSelection();
        CustomerDropdown.DataTextField = dataSet.Tables[0].Columns["cust_id"].ToString();
        CustomerDropdown.DataValueField = dataSet.Tables[0].Columns["cust_id"].ToString();
        CustomerDropdown.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];  //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist  
                                                          // CustomerDropdown.Items[0].Selected = true;
        CustomerDropdown.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist 
        CustomerDropdown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
        CustomerDropdown.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("All"));
        CustomerDropdown.SelectedIndex=0; ---> Possible solution
```

?

Got from: [Reference](https://meeraacademy.com/dropdownlist-control-in-asp-net/)

Comment: This selects the right index but the dropdown list doesn't refresh so it doesn't matter. I edited my original question to ask essentially how to refresh the dropdown list.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with refreshing the list? isnt your line "CustomerDropdown.Items.Clear();"  already clearing the previous data?

Comment: So if I ```Clear()``` and/or do ```CustomerDropdown.SelectedIndex = 0;``` it will do that but it won't reflect on the screen on the dropdown list.  I'm wondering if it's a postback issue.  It's driving me nuts because this should be easy.

Comment: I've found a similar question with the postback thing too, did you try it? [link](https://www.csharp-code.com/2009/03/how-to-use-dropdownlist-autopostback.html)

Comment: I read that exact page and have my dropdown list set like so: ```<asp:DropDownList ID="CustomerDropdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnDropDownOnChangeDoThis" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                        </asp:DropDownList>```

Comment: So whats in your OnSelectedIndexChanged method? you could add there the Clear and Selectedindex code